# Screenshot of zoomed area of textureview

Tags: android, zooming, screenshot, textureview

i am facing a problem with my code. 
I have used textureview to display camera streaming and i can zoom it as well.
Now my problem is want to take screenshot of zoomed area but when i do that in code it saved whole image what camera is capturing, not only the zoomed area. 
So is there any solution where i can screenshot only those content what i have zoomed rather that whole orignal textureview?